# Trying to make a binary tree for Strings

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
insert(char * key, struct node *leaf, int x)
{
    if (x==1) //Customer
    {
        if( strcmp(leaf->customer.IDNo,root->customer.IDNo)==0 )
        {
            *leaf = (struct node) malloc(101);
            *leaf->customer.IDNo = key;
            /* initialize the children to null */
            (*leaf)->left = 0;
            (*leaf)->right = 0;
        }

        else if(strcmp(key,(*leaf)->customer.IDNo)<0)
        {
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
        }

        else if(strcmp(key,(*leaf)->customer.IDNo)>0)
        {
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
        }
    }

    else //Product
    {
        if( strcmp(leaf->product.ProdName,root->product.ProdName)==0 )
        {
            *leaf = (struct node) malloc(101);
            (*leaf)->product.ProdName = key;
            /* initialize the children to null */
            (*leaf)->left = 0;
            (*leaf)->right = 0;
        }

        else if(strcmp(key,(*leaf)->product.ProdName)<0)
        {
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
        }

        else if(strcmp(key,(*leaf)->product.ProdName)>0)
        {
            insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
        }
    }
}
```

45,64 conversion to a non-scalar type requestion
46 assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
48,49,51,53,55,57,65,67,68,70,72,74,76 invalid type argument of -> (have struct node)
53,57,72,76 too few arguments to function 'insert'

```
Node *search(char * key, struct node *leaf,int x)
{
    struct node * y;

    if (x==1)
    {
        if( leaf != 0 )
        {
            if(strcmp(key,leaf->customer.IDNo)==0)
            {
                y= leaf;
            }

            else if(strcmp(key,leaf->customer.IDNo)<0)
            {
                y= search(key, leaf->left);
            }

            else
            {
                y= search(key, leaf->right);
            }
        }
    }

    else if (x==2)
    {

        if( leaf != 0 )
        {
            if(strcmp(key,leaf->product.ProdName)==0)
            {
                y= leaf;
            }

            else if(strcmp(key,leaf->product.ProdName)<0)
            {
                y= search(key, leaf->left);
            }

            else
            {
                y= search(key, leaf->right);
            }
        }
    }

    else y= 0;
    return y;
}
```

94,98,112 too few arguments to function 'search'

The errors which occur on multiple lines are similar so all I need is instructions on how to fix one of them and I can do the rest.

Comment: please format and indent your code properly.

Comment: Woah, this took some time to format...

Comment: The line numbers don't help when we don't know which actual lines of code they correspond to.

Answer (score 4):

You have numerous problems where you are mixing up pointers and what they are pointing at.

For example, in this code:

```
*leaf = (struct node) malloc(101);
```

You have several serious problems:

1. malloc returns a pointer to memory, not a concrete struct.  As a result, trying to cast its returned pointer to a struct node will not work.  You should cast it to a struct node* (a pointer to a node) rather than a concrete node.
2. leaf is a pointer to a node.  If you try to dereference it and set it equal to the node on the other side, you will try to write to the memory pointed at by node, rather than changing where the pointer is pointing.  You probably want to do something else (described below).
3. It is extremely unsafe and wasteful to pass in an arbitrary number like 101 into malloc.  You should instead ask malloc to give you the right amount of space by passing in sizeof(struct node).

More importantly, though, is the problem that you are trying to change the leaf pointer inside of your insert function, but are passing leaf in by value.  In order to change which node the leaf pointer points at, you should be passing in a pointer to the leaf pointer, rather than the leaf pointer itself.  Try changing the signature to use a `struct node** leaf`, then update your code so that you reassign the pointer pointed at by leaf within your code.

There are numerous other pointer errors here, but ultimately I think they all stem from confusing pointers and what they point at.  When fixing your code, please try to keep in mind whether you want to change the object your pointer points to, or which object is being pointed at in the first place.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "You should cast it to a `struct node*` (a pointer to a node) rather than a concrete node." How about "You should not cast it *at all* when compiling a C program, as implicit cast from `void *` to `type *` is automatic." And +1, helluva job formatting that spaghetti.

Comment: @WhozCraig- Oh whoops, this is C, not C++. :-) Also, credit for reformatting the code doesn't go to me; I just retained it.

Comment: Still, nice answer, esp the summary on the OP giving a hard-look at their pointer usage.

Comment: Thanks that arranged it a little, but now I'm getting different errors...
The compiler's telling me that there's a request for 'customer', 'left', 'right', and 'product' in something not a structure or union...can somebody explain please?
Sorry I'm still just an amateur =/

Comment: @EdwardBamber- I honestly think you need to work on a simpler piece of code than this.  I get the sense that you don't have a strong sense of how to use pointers, so working on some simpler, non-recursive code might be useful here.

Comment: I dont have the time for that, this code is due in less than 5 days so I'm really pressed for time now. Wouldn't be asking for help if it weren't urgent trust me =/

Comment: @EdwardBamber- The specific error you're getting means that you're trying to use the dot operator on something that isn't a struct.  It probably means that you need to use `->` instead of `.`.  For future reference, don't hesitate to Google error messages you get - often you can get very good info.  I understand that this is due soon, but it's really not my place to do your assignment for you.